# Edges orange when I haven't selected them

Tags: edit-mode, edges, select

[image: orange edges]My edges are orange when I haven't even selected them.

Thing i've tried:

1. restarting blender
2. clicking on select then select none
3. clicking on the background
4. checking if they have a crease or not

Comment: Hello, maybe you've enabled Wireframe in the Viewport Overlays panel even though it doesn't seem to be the problem, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a *Minimal Dark* theme, those are UV seams.

This theme colors UV seams orange (as opposed to the classic red)
Selected edges in this theme are blue (as opposed to the classic orange)

To get the classic colors, change your theme to Blender Dark.

[image]

Comment: That worked! thank you